# SSH cannot connect to linux, permission denied

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox

I run a Ubuntu Server in my virtualbox, and have installed openssh-server and openssh-client. The network of virtualbox is Host-Only, and I set its IP 192.168.0.100

Then I try to connect to the virtual machine use SSH

Here is cmd:

```
ssh -v slave@192.168.0.100
```

Then

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.100 [192.168.0.100] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/wang/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/wang/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/wang/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/wang/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/wang/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/wang/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA c4:05:01:3c:6d:18:ca:e5:81:86:79:7a:03:1d:30:d2
debug1: Host '192.168.0.100' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/wang/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/wang/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wang/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/wang/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

And it tells me to input password, the public key of ssh in virtualbox is 123456, but it does not works, and i tried root password, it still does't work.

```
slave@192.168.0.100's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
slave@192.168.0.100's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
slave@192.168.0.100's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

What can I do? Please help me.

Comment: The public key is `123456`? That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Have you tried logging in as `root` with the root password?

Comment: have you set a user password? have you generated proper public/private keys and inserted them into your ~/authorized_hosts?